# how to override iphone silent mode or do-not-disturb?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile, app-store

I'm building an iPhone app that need only one thing
to make a noise **even** if the phone is on "silent" / "do not disturb" mode.
example: me and my wife will install the app - she will send me a push notification and my phone(on silent mode) will trigger the sound --- that's it.
*** all the "Emergency Bypass" feature is no good because i need to do it through my app only.

I've read some answers saying that a way to do it is saving an audio file on the device and when the push arrive to play this audio file on the background and that will override the silent mode like the alarm clock that override my silent mode - unfortunately it didn't work (no sound)

yes - many told my that it couldn't be done, i am looking for away to DO IT. 
if you have any suggestions i would love to hear them or any alternatives how i can make this scenario succeed.
maybe create a "fake" silent mode that will mute all other sounds other then my push/sms or anything else to make it work.

being working on this for 2 month now and would love to find away to do it, any way :)
thanx

Comment: Just a comment here.  Apparently it *is* possible as that's exactly what the TrackR app does. TrackR makes a device called Pixel that's a bluetooth 'fob' you attach to your keys to help find them, but it also has the reverse-finding feature where if you press a button on the fob, it makes your phone play a loud sound.  It not only bypasses the mute switch, but even the 'Do Not Disturb' feature. Further, if you had your volume turned down, it raises it to 100%. I've been trying to find out how they do this but they don't answer support about their own products, let alone how they wrote the app.